# Correct order in footnote citation for revised edition and volume details

Tags: citations, footnotes, chicago-manual-of-style

What comes first in a citation that must include revised edition and volume details? Looking for CMOS guidance on this but haven't found an example that corresponds to my specific case. I've written the following citation:

* Max von Boehn and Oskar Fischel, *Die Mode:
Menschen und Moden im neunzehnten Jahrhundert*,
vol. 3 (München: F. Bruckmann, 1908), pp. 122–23,
trans. M. Edwardes as *Modes and Manners of the
Nine­teenth Century*, rev. ed., vol. 3 (London: J. M. 
Dent, 1927), p. 129. [Citation added this edition.]

Only the 1927 English translation is a revised edition, not the original German.

Are we kosher or should volume precede revised edition? And should a comma follow? Looking to spot any style errors in this complex citation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such details will depend on the place you want to publish. Check with the editor or equivalent authority in that place. Look at how previous authors in the same place have done things.

Comment: The work was written by a famous architect and originally published in the 1950s by OUP with incomplete citations for quoted sources. The heirs are republishing it, which I'm overseeing and addressing some of OUP's editorial oversights. Yes, consulting prior examples is always the first route taken. I've plowed CMOS (the style guide followed by the publisher, albeit with a few house style adjustments) and a selection of other titles for a matching example, to no avail as of yet. The primary question is the order of revised edition and volume (and does a comma follow the last).

Comment: As I understand it your citation should look like this: Max von Boehn and Oskar Fischel, *Modes and Manners of the Nine­teenth Century*, trans. M. Edwardes, vol. 3, rev. ed. (London: J. M.  Dent, 1927), p. 129. || You are quoting from the translation, so do not give the original edition as source.